# SAS DDE write a hpyerlink into one cell failed

Tags: excel, hyperlink, sas, dde

I want to write a hyperlink work into one cell but failed.

```
filename xlSheet1 dde "Excel|&ddestr.Report!R&insertpos.C1:R&insertpos.0C8";

data _null_;
file xlSheet1;
e = '=HYPERLINK("c:\work\test.txt","FAILED")';
put e;
run;
```

But can only write the first part of the string as "=HYPERLINK("c:\work\test.txt", ", the second parameter was lost. The link can also works but only 0 displayed.

How to fix? i want them everything in one cell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question whether the outermost quotes you're using are single quotes or double quotes, as you've used single quotes in the code snippet but then double quotes in the text below. If you're using only double quotes, try the following and see if it works for you:

```
filename xlSheet1 dde "Excel|&ddestr.Report!R&insertpos.C1:R&insertpos.0C8";

data _null_;
file xlSheet1;
e = "=HYPERLINK(""c:\work\test.txt"",""FAILED"")";
put e;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works.
I also tried the string concatenation and it also work, such as
d = '=HYPERLINK("' || cat("&outlib","\&formname._rm1rm2.xlsx") || '","'||"&formname._rm1rm2"||'"';